# how to extract selective data from multiple excel workbooks to another workbook without having to write VBA Codes (I am not a developer)

Tags: excel, excel-2013

how to extract selective data from multiple excel workbooks to another workbook without having to write VBA Codes (I am not a developer).
I tried to use Power Query Editor but it has been discontinued by Microsoft for Excel 2013.

Comment: There are many ways to do that. Which one to recommend depends upon what kind of data to extract, where the files are, and what to do with the extracted data. However, since you tried to become familiar with Power Query, the good news is that it only was introduced in 2013 (I believe) and is very much up and coming now. However, it needs to be enabled. You can google for instructions.

Comment: @Variatus thank you so much. So the files are all MS excel workbooks with various columns of product names, their retails sales number (actual), their sales forecast number, and so on. All the files are in one folder. The source files have plenty of other columns other than what I mentioned above and I need only the relevant ones skipping the non-relevant columns. Then I wish those required columns' data to be put together into a new excel file where I can do my calculations for that data.

Comment: I went on Microsoft's website and found that they have discontinued Power Query for 2013 and 2010. I have Excel 2013 installed on my laptop and when I tried to download and install the Power Query add-in from Microsoft's website, it showed me an error stating to download 64 bit MS Excel 2013 which I already have.